# expect clause in GroovyTestCase

Tags: java, groovy, junit

```
@Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException)
void testNullArgument()
{
    archiveUtility.process(lstFileName, "", workflowId)

}
```

When I call process method on archiveUtility object it throws an IllegalArgumentException but my test still fails even though I have declared the test to expect IllegalArgumentException. This is a groovyTestCase. Am unable to figure out why so ? Any thoughts ?

Comment: How are you running these test cases? Which version of groovy are your using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In GroovyTestCase you can use [**shouldFail**](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/GroovyTestCase.html#shouldFail%28java.lang.Class,%20groovy.lang.Closure%29). Try this:

```
void testNullArgument()
{
    shouldFail(IllegalArgumentException)
    {
        archiveUtility.process(lstFileName, "", workflowId)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a .class (expected=IllegalArgumentException.class) ?